# Matlab terminate code if warning occurs

Tags: matlab, numerical-linear-algebra

I am running a code where by I want to maximise a parameter (basically the range of integration) by increasing it in steps until a warning occurs. It involves inverting a linear system Ax=b and I want the script to stop if a warning like the following occurs:

Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be
inaccurate. RCOND =  1.530374e-16.

Does anyone know of a method to do this?

Comment: Probably better to post this question on stackoverflow...

Comment: First modify the warning to be an error, then catch it with try/catch.  See [ http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/trapping-warnings-efficiently/ ].  Check here [ http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/10/18/controlling-warning-messages-and-state/ ] if you need a reliable way to figure out exactly which warning to modify

Comment: I agree with @5xum – this is a programming question rather than a math question. In fact there's already [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431743/conversion-of-warnings-to-errors-in-matlab) on StackOverflow with several answers.

Answer (score 0):

$RCOND$ is the reciprocal of conditional number. Smaller it is, closer to singlular the matrix is. Perhaps the numbers of your matrix is too small, you can try to change the initial conditions or enlarge the values by a certain proportion. If you need the inverse of a matrix, you can use pinv().

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this (clean the warning and throwing an error when the warning occurs):

```
n = 20;
A = rand(n);
A = A^10;

lastwarn('');
x = A \ ones(n,1);
if (~isempty(lastwarn))
    error(lastwarn);
end
```